# Python- using sum in for loop with an error

Tags: python, sum

Why should I write this program  like this(first way) :

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1, 10):
    if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0):
        sum = sum + i
print(sum)
```

Why cant I write like this?(second way) :

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0):
    print(sum(i))
```

In second way I receive this error :

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

What does this error mean exactly?
Where may I use sum function? Where not?

Must I make a list to use sum function?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The second one should just be `print(i)` since you only have one value

Comment: you have overwrite the inbuild function `sum` to a int variable `sum`, so since you cant iterate over a integer you are geting this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) says, the first argument to the builtin function `sum()` needs to be an iterable.

Lists and tuples are examples of iterables. An int is not an iterable.

Now, in your first approach, `sum` is a variable that you have introduced, and unfortunately it has the same name as the built-in function. This should, in general, be avoided (introducing user-defined names that conflict with names of standard functions or modules)

In your second approach, `sum` refers to the built-in function of that name, and it expects an iterable (eg, list or tuple) as its first argument, but your are passing `i`, which is an `int` object

Comment: Thanks a lot . It was helpful

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote `sum=0` you have overwritten the python function `sum()`.
so when you write `sum(1)` you ask python to calculate `0(1)` which is not possible since `0` is not iterable

In general, it is not advised to assign `sum` to a value

What could work is either of the following codes:

```
s=0
for i in range(1, 10):
   if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0):
       s+=1
       print(s)
```

or better if you want to use the sum function:

```
print(sum([i for i in range(10) if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0)]))
```

Comment: "you ask python to calculate `0(1)`". That is *not* the correct explanation for why the error "int object is not iterable" occurred.